# mvc 5 dropdownlistfor from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Working with MVC 5 and can't seem to bind the dropdownlistfor to my model.  The DisplayNameFor binds correctly.  Here is my view.

```
<div class="row">
    <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
    <hr />
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="div1">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="@Url.Action("GetKeys", "Encryption")">
            <div class="form-group">
              @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CarrierID)
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CarrierID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Carriers, "id", "Name"), "----Select a  Carrier----")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CarrierID)
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Model looks like this

```
[Key]
        public System.Guid EncryptionID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Carrier Name:")]
        public string CarrierID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CarrierNames { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Text to Encrypt:")]
        public string txtText { get; set; }

        public string Thumbprint { get; set; }
```

Intelisense shows that model does not contain a definition for CarrierID, thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested your code and that property is showing up in intellisense fine for me VS2013 premium.

Maybe its an issue with your VS?

Worth mentioning I tested the form post and can see the value coming through from the dropdown changing when changing a viewbag selectlist to this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CarrierID, MyModel.MySelectListItems())


    public static IList<SelectListItem> MySelectListItems()
    {
        return new List<SelectListItem>{
            new SelectListItem {Text = "option1", Value = "1"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "option2", Value = "2"}
        };
    }
```

Comment: Nah, I get the same error at run-time.  Also, to make note, this is pulled from a DbSet.  So the model on the view is an IEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

So, I've found the solution.  It was the way the elements were being referenced.

```
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ElementAt<Professional_Services_Tools.Models.t_ConfigBasedEncryption>(0).CarrierID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Carriers, "Value", "Text"), "----Select a  Carrier----")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ElementAt<Professional_Services_Tools.Models.t_ConfigBasedEncryption>(0).CarrierID)
```

Comment: That is not a solution. It will never bind to you model when you submit - your generating a `name` attribute that has no relationship to your model.